# How to say I was in good health for some amount of time before having caught a cold?

Tags: sentence-construction, expressions

I want to say it in English that I was in good health for some amount of time before I got a cold (I have some difficulty with its grammar)

I wanted to say "Before I was caught a cold, I had been in good health for nearly three years".

But it seems weird, I've never heard such thing.

Comment: Most people would say that have a mere common cold does not stop you being in 'good health'.

Comment: Thanks,Haha! I was trying to find an appropriate word for that but I failed. In fact I was trying to say there was nothing other than a cold which broke the healthy chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence is good, except that one says "Before I caught a cold, ...". That means the same as "Before I got a cold, ...". The clause that describes your three years of good health is perfect.

Comment: Thanks! That's perfectly explained.